# Is Kaveri a HSA-compliant processor?

Tags: gpu, preemption

I have looked at lots of [HSA introductions](http://developer.amd.com/resources/heterogeneous-computing/what-is-heterogeneous-system-architecture-hsa/) and find that a HSA-compliant GPU should be preemptible and support context switch.

But the Wikipedia article "[AMD Accelerated Processing Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Accelerated_Processing_Unit)" says GPU compute context switch, GPU graphics preemption will have support in Carizzo APU (2015).

So I wonder whether Kaveri is a HSA-compliant processor?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe query a mail to the manufacturer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaveri is a 1st generation HSA-compliant APU.
As a 1st generation, it is still missing some features of the HSA specification. One of those features is Mid-wave preemption, which means the ability to preempt a graphic/compute work in the middle, context-switch to a different wave (work) and then resume the original wave.

Without this feature, Kaveri needs to finish the wave and only then can it move to a different wave.

Having said that, there is already an infrastructure for running HSA applications on Kaveri in Linux (Ubuntu 13/14). See https://github.com/HSAFoundation/Linux-HSA-Drivers-And-Images-AMD for kernel bits and https://github.com/HSAFoundation/Okra-Interface-to-HSA-Device for userspace bits.

This infrastructure also supports the Aparapi and Sumatra projects on Kaveri - running Java code on the GPU.

Hope this helps.